# Doing Makeup with your Mouth

Tags: anatomy, tools

The tricrurals are humanoid creatures without arms or feet. Their jaws are replaced by a set of tentacles. These tentacles are around 10cm long and are as flexible as human fingers, though they can bend in any direction. There are 6 tentacles, which point downwards when resting. They have eyes and can see

While most tasks can be done just as in humans, there are some things which may be harder, such as putting on makeup

In terms of materials and manufacturing, they have modern technology. Their makeup is similar in substance to modern day makeup, and there is makeup that's applied to all parts of the face. They have mirrors to see themselve

Given this, what sort of tools could these humanoids use to apply their makeup?

Ideally the tools should be simple and easy to make, as well as being lightweight and easy to use. They shouldn't need another person to help them

Comment: If their tentacles are as flexible as human fingers, why can't they grip the same kinds of tools used by humanoids? You can grip a brush or a puff with a tentacle just fine.

Comment: @stix But how would they reach their face?

Comment: @IchthysKing 10cm seems plenty long to reach your face when they are already on your face. But if they can't move anything larger than the size of a fist, then how did they get any technology, let alone modern technology, to begin with? I find that less believable than the fact they can do make-up.

Comment: They are humanoid in shape, without arms and legs, but instead got 10cm tentacle beard... then I'm actually more curious about how they walk or wipe their butts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can lay the makeup on a fixed substrate using their tentacles and then rub their faces on the substrate.

The substrate can have various shapes, according to the need: flat, conic, brush-like and so on.